# Drawing non-pixelated lines using processing on canvas

Tags: html, canvas, processing

I am using processing to draw lines on canvas. My code is quite simple:

```
processing.line(line.origin.x, line.origin.y, line.destination.x, line.destination.y);`
```

But I get pixelated lines:

[image]

How do I draw non-pixelated precise lines?

Comment: Use svg... Canvas and thus processingjs is a pixel drawing area. Also, if you do resize your canvas with css, don't. canvas pixel size should be the same as your screen one, so you should not notice it.

Comment: Can you post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Are you drawing in `draw()`? If so are you using a call to `background()`?

Comment: @Shubham Goyal Kaiido's suggestion is good. Either you resize the canvas element and redraw at the full size or use an SVG renderer. AFAIK Processing.js only renders using Canvas (pixels), but you can use [p5.js](http://p5js.org) with the [p5.SVG.js](https://github.com/zenozeng/p5.js-svg/blob/master/doc/getting-started.md) addon which enabled SVG rendering with Processing like syntax in javascript.

Answer (score 1):

If your line code is inside your draw function it will be pixelated unless you add a background color above it.
So you can add a background color in your draw function or you could instead put your line code in the setup function. Either should remove the pixelation.